# bash: permission denied Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, xorg, vnc

i used this command to start x11vnc at startup, this command is from [here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aMaverick#X11VNC_Server). And here is the command:

```
echo "/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/x11vnc.pass -o ~/.vnc/x11vnc.log -loopbg -display :0" > ~/.config/autostart/x11vnc.sh 
chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/x11vnc.sh
```

but when i press enter, i got this permission denied message

`"bash: /home/user/.config/autostartx/x11vnc.sh Permission Denied"`

i hope someone can help me. thnx

Comment: the problem may be because you do not own the file. check who owns the file by running `ls -l ~/.config/autostartx/x11vnc.sh`  it should  have 2 user names in the line and the first should be yours else you will have to run with sudo to do this.

Comment: you started it as root once.  remove it as root and it should regenerate.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal:

```
cd ~
sudo chmod -R o+rw .config .vnc
sudo chown -R <your_user_name> .config .vnc
```

this ensures you can access all the files, even if you accidently created them as root.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error is raised is  probably because you are lacking ownership of the file ~/.config/autostart... Try running the command with 'sudo'. This command temporarily gives you super user status so that when you run the command you have access to all the necessary files. However be careful since these files are protected for a reason so just double check the command will act in the way you intend.

```
sudo echo "/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/x11vnc.pass -o ~/.vnc/x11vnc.log -loopbg -display :0" > ~/.config/autostart/x11vnc.sh 
chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/x11vnc.sh
```